# How to have user input info and also confirm input

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a function that has the user input their name and then confirm their name is correct before continuing. If the name is not correct I want them to be able to go back in and change their name. but I can't figure out how to return the name to the global. I've played around with what seems like a million different ways, but these are the two most recent ways I've tried....

```
def assign_name():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    confirm = input(f"is {name} correct?  Y/N")
    if confirm != 'y':
        assign_name()
    else:
        print(name)  ### tester
        return name


my_name = assign_name()
print(my_name)  ### tester


################################

def assign_name(name):
    confirm = input(f"is {name} your name?  Y/N")
    if confirm != 'y':
        assign_name(input("What is your name?"))
    else: 
        print(name)  ### tester
        return(name)



my_name = assign_name(input("What is your name?"))
```

Comment: What do you mean "return to global"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Samaksh - i want the name that is entered to be stored in the my_name variable. but if I print the my_name after running it through i only get "None"

Comment: Peter - Unfortunately it has not. I've read through that post already and couldn't see how any of it helped my situation

Comment: @Healfdene https://repl.it/repls/JointTerribleVirtualmachines your code works as it is, maybe you are doing something else?

Comment: @Healfdene after ```if confirm != 'y': ``` return your function call .i.e ```return assign_name() ``` , you are not retuning in if stattement obiviously it will return None by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed implementation using the recursive approach you've attempted:

```
def assign_name():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    confirm = input(f"Is {name} correct? (Y/N) ")
    if confirm.lower() != 'y':
        return assign_name()
    return name

my_name = assign_name()
print(my_name)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test_recursion.py
What is your name? first
Is first correct? (Y/N) n
What is your name? second
Is second correct? (Y/N) y
second
```

However, recursion isn't an efficient approach in this case. It more efficient to use a `while` loop and not incur the overhead of repeated function calls and variable instantiation.

Here's an alternative approach:

```
def assign_name():
    while True:
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        confirm = input(f"Is {name} correct? (Y/N) ")
        if confirm.lower() == 'y':
            break
    return name

my_name = assign_name()
print(my_name)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test_loop.py
What is your name? first
Is first correct? (Y/N) n
What is your name? second
Is second correct? (Y/N) y
second
```

---

Regarding your original implementation attempt:

You do not return the result of the recursive function call. Since your `return` statement is within the `else` block, no `return` statement is ever called for your initial invocation of the function. That's why `None` is returned.

If your `return` statement was not within the `else` block, it would still be problematic as you would end up returning the initial value provided, essentially disregarding the work performed via recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to go about it. When it comes to getting variables passed around between functions you have three options:

1. Use global statement inside your functions (a lot of people will
   flame you for it.....)
   2.Pass around functions as the args to other
   functions (makes a fun game) 
   3.Use classes

   ```
   def assignName():
     name = input("Whats your name?")
     while not checkName(name):
       assignName()

     return name

   def checkName(name):
     if input(f"Is {name} correct?"): return name

   name = assignName()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
def assign_name():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    confirm = input(f"is {name} correct?  y/n ")
    if confirm != 'y':
        name = input("What is your name? ")
    else:
        name = name  ### tester
        print(name)
        return name


my_name = assign_name()
print(my_name, "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code fails to assign the new user input to `name`. Try this:

```
def assign_name():
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    confirm = input(f'is {name} correct? Y/N')
    if confirm != 'Y':
        name = assign_name()
    return name
```

There is an issue with the above solution: recursion depth. I doubt it would happen in normal use of this function, but it's good to note that a frame is added to the stack each time the user resubmits a name. Eventually the program will exceed the maximum stack size or the available memory. Also, be certain to maintain consistent case or use a case-insensitive comparison, i.e. `'Y' != 'y'`

Give it the old while-loop treatment in order to avoid stack height problems:

```
def assign_name():
    is_correct = False
    while not is_correct:
        name = input('What is your name? ')
        is_correct = input(f'is {name} correct? Y/N') == 'Y'
    return name
```